# Visualizing Plane Partitions in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I wrote a simple MATLAB script to generate a 50x50 matrix $D$, which is a [plane partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_partition).

Plane partitions are usually represented graphically as stacks of cubes. How do I realise this visualisation in MATLAB? I have played around  with the HIST function to no avail. I got close with mesh(D), but the results were pretty ugly...

$$[image: Hey! I'm not ugly!]$$

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `bar3` might help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding an answer for completeness:

Use the bar3 function as [explained in the docs](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/bar3.html).